# How to receive the Curl Request in Web API

Tags: c#, curl, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to receive the curl request in my web API method. Below is the request that will be send by the user. I am trying to receive this request in web api but i am not able to do this.

Can you please suggest me how can i do this.

```
Array
(
    [post_data] => Array
        (
            [DL] => 2
            [ID] => 8NNGQ8Q5
            [ShipCity] => CLEARWATER
            [ShipState] => FL
            [ShipZip] => 33762
            [ShipCountry] => US
        )
```

**Trying to create a web API method for the same.**

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetQuote(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] Request model)
        {
            try
            {
                var abf = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, abf);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

        }
```

Comment: You are calling Async Method to receive.  This will not work as your main method is not async.  You need to make your method async and use await to receive the response.

Comment: @AliK thanks for your reply i have not created earlier can you help me to how to write this function.

Comment: Simple search for “c# httpclient tutoris" will help as many tutorials are available.

Comment: @AliK trying to find the example but not get any according to my problem. Can you share anyone that will help me

Comment: Do this                 var abf = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; and put debug on return line and you can see result of abf; Hope this helps

Comment: @AliK i am getting data as
 ------------------------526198233023550000595618
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="DL"

2
----------------------------526198233023550000595618
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ID"

8NNGQ8Q5

Comment: @AliK can i get all value as a array of object . So if user post array of data i can get as a array.  Currently i am getting value separately  as string DL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["DL"];

Comment: It looks like you are receiving a form from your api call.  To convert and read this you will need to do some processing yourself like parsing form  using c#.  Can't really give you the code for this as don't have it to hand but there are a few examples online when searching "parsing form data in c#".